# How use Kendo UI Editor in asp.net mvc3 with razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, editor, kendo-ui

I'm using editor from Kendo UI, so I have big problem.

I don't know how display items which are returned by editor.

Editor convert something like:

```
<img src="someurl" />
```

to:

```
lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;someurl&quot;/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

and I keep converted string in database, and try display it with:

```
@Html.Raw(item.description)
```

where description is string returned by kendo.

**So I have no idea how display it correctly in my View**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post how the relevant part of your view looks like?

Comment: Can you also post where you define the Kendo UI editor in your view? And also the form how you post the data?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an option of the KendeUI editor called `encoded` which configures whether the Editor should submit encoded HTML tags or not.

The default value for `encoded` is `true`

If you wan't to store the unencoded text use this sniplet when creating your editor:

```
$("#Editor").kendoEditor({
     encoded: false
 });
```

But because you are not sending encoded text to the server the Asp.net request validator kicks in and it will abort your request.

If you are using strongly typed views what you can do is to use the `AllowHtmlAttribute` on your model property:

View:

```
@model MyModel

@using(Html.BeginForm("SomeAction", "SomeController"))
{
     @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Editor)
     <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
      $("#Editor").kendoEditor({
        encoded: false
      });
   });
</script>
```

Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Editor { get; set; }
}
```

Controller action

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(MyModel myModel)
{
    //Save to db, etc.
}
```

You also need to set the following in your web.config or this attribute won't have effect in .NET 4.0:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it solve only half of my problem becouse there are new problems with it. If I set this option to `false` I have problem with quotes and an error: `A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client`. So maybe better way is set `encoded: true` and use some conversion to encode it in controller? Any ideas how?

Comment: Use the `[AllowHtml]` attribute for the properties which are bound for the KendoUI editor.

Comment: I'm not sure where I should add `[AllowHtml]` attribute.

Comment: @MateuszRogulski I've update my answer with some additional info.

Comment: from [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/marcinon/2010/11/09/granular-request-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3/): In MVC 2 running on .NET 4 you had to set `requestValidationMode="2.0"` in order to turn request validation off. In MVC 3 this is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 9):

I found this solution for MVC:
in View

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.Kendo().EditorFor(model => model.HtmlField).Encode(false))
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HtmlField)
</div>
```

in model:

```
   [DataType(DataType.Html)]
   [AllowHtml]
   public string HtmlField{ get; set; }
```

That was enough

Comment: his just worked for me!!!!!!!!!!   The Update Crud was not hitting the controller when using Html.Kendo().EditorFor in a template for the grid pop up window.  I added the two attributes above and it worked.  Wish I could give you 10 upvotes!!

Answer (score 6):

Simplier way to do it is make changes in controller, no in view and model. So:

**View**

```
$("#Editor").kendoEditor();
```

**Model**

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Editor { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
Editor = Server.HtmlDecode(Editor);
```

[HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwzhtkke.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The editor templates generated from the .NET Wrappers aren't working any more. Here is a fix.

http://pknopf.com/blog/kendo-ui-editor-templates-for-asp-net